# Apps for industries

Tags: ros, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friends,

I'm working on turtle bot from last one year, i want to make a application with my friends to industries on this technology(ROS).

Any one can suggest me the best application to industries.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58077/apps-for-industries.../) by [learner](https://answers.ros.org/users/4414/learner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-13**:
I think this is not a proper question for ROS Answers. By the way, I have a lot of ideas. If you invest 3 million dollars on me then I shall let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it's a reasonable question. The idea on the turtlebot was good - it just ran into the problem that development got terminated and there wasn't a scrap of documentation (except for browsing code) that explained how it worked.

We're actually currently moving towards that model ourselves and will be upgrading the idea of an appable robot over the next couple of months. Hopefully we'll land a prototype of it in hydro for turtlebot.

I'll be announcing a design review for it on ros users in the coming days. In the meantime, we've got some information on the ros wiki for the [rocon_app_platform](http://ros.org/wiki/rocon_app_platform). Input would be welcome.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-14**:
Hmmm... A robot is different from a PC or iPad because it is more specialized. Some robots need a good arm but just a wheelbase while others want good legs but simple arms, etc. So how to design a general-purpose app-able robot?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-14**:
Dive into the available documentation and you will find out! :-) Don't miss to take a look at the [concert](http://ros.org/wiki/rocon_concert). We will be happy to provide more information in case you have specific questions.